# A strange heat transfer problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I saw this problem in a physics textbook:

> - Suppose we have a bunch of identical milk bottles at temperature    $t_x$.
> - Drop one of them into a thermal insulated box of water, wait for    equilibrium, then take it out, then drop the next milk bottle in,
>     repeat the process.
> - Initial temperature of the water in the box is $t_0 =    36^{\circ}\text{C}$. The first bottle right after taken out has
>     temperature $t_1=33^{\circ}\text{C} $, **the second bottle right
>
>     after taken out has temperature $t_2=36.5^{\circ}\text{C} $**, assume
>     heat loss is negligible.
>
> Questions:
>
> 1. Find $t_x$
> 2. After how many bottles will the water temperature in the box drop
>      to below $25^{\circ}\text{C} $?

At first this looks like a simple problem involving heat equation $\Delta q = mc \Delta T$, then I was quite perplexed by the figures given, how can $t_2$ jump to $36.5^{\circ}\text{C} $? I have thought about phase change, I have thought about water mass vaporizes somehow... but it doesn't really make sense how $t_2$ could be higher than $t_0$. Could there be some process I am missing here?

Should I just conclude that it is a typo?

Comment: Yes it's a typo. The temperature of the water is $33$ºC after the first bottle is removed and $t_x \lt 33$ºC so the temperature cannot rise after the second bottle has been allowed to equilibrate.